# How to strip string from a string and push into array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am running the following:

```
var countries = [];
$("#usp-custom-3 option").each(function() {
  var single = $(this).text();
  if($(single == "United States of America")) {
    $(this).text() == "United States";
  }
  countries.push(single);
  console.log(single);
});
```

Basically what I am trying to do is to convert `United States of America` into `United States` before to push it into array together with the rest of the countries as I have a list of countries in a `select option`.

Comment: maybe `single == "United States";` ? since single is the object you pass to your array

Comment: push `$(this).text() ` instead single, because you are not assigning to `single`

Comment: why a downvote?

Comment: By the way, you dont need to wrap everything into $()...

Comment: @Jonasw you mean not having a .each() at all?

Comment: @rob.m cause youre mixing up =,==,=== in a very very confusing way, making your code do nothing :/ ( not my downvote, however i can understand that)

Comment: @rob.m no, thats the only line it may be useful.

Comment: @Jonasw perhaps if it was working and I was right I wouldn't have asked a question I guess

Comment: @rob.m a proper look into the docs (https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Vergleichsoperatoren , https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Zuweisungsoperator ) wouldve probably solved your problem...

Comment: @Jonasw yeah i agree, we should close stackoverflow and just have links to docs.

Comment: @rob.m no, there are good questions, and i havent downvoted / flagged this question, but before asking, everyone should have a look into the docs, as 50% of the problems are simple typos

Comment: @Jonasw probably I had to, yet I am in between so many lines on my code and I'm all by myself that I needed a quick help more than anything else. I see your point, but pease do see mine. Thanks tho

Comment: @rob.m yeah thats fine, but when i write code that is simply not working, I rather shutdown my computer and have a look at it again the next day, often these mistakes are obvious... ( another tip: $().text()="sth" will throw an error, do $().text("sth") if you want to change the text...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var countries = [];

  $("#usp-custom-3 option").each(function() {
    var single = $(this).text();
    if(single == "United States of America") {
     single= "United States";
    }
    countries.push(single);
    console.log(single);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
var countries = [];
$("#usp-custom-3 option").each(function () {
    var single = $(this).text();
    if (single == "United States of America") {
        single = "United States";
    }
    countries.push(single);
    console.log(single);
});

console.log(countries);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="usp-custom-3">
   <option>United States of America</option>
   <option>India</option>
   <option>UK</option>
   <option>United States of America</option>
   <option>India</option>
   <option>UK</option>
   <option>United States of America</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var countries = [];
$("#usp-custom-3 option").each(function () {
    var single = $(this).text();
    if (single == "United States of America") {
        single = "United States";
    }
    countries.push(single);
    console.log(single);
});
```

try this one.

Comment: `==`is not an assignment operator.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed your problem and added a little bit refactoring.

```
var countries = [];
var us = 'United States';
var usa = 'United States of America';

$("#usp-custom-3 option").each(function() {
  var single = $(this); //gets jquery instance of the element
  if(single.text() == usa) { //Check if its text is USA
    single.text(us); //Replace the option text with 'United States'
  }
  countries.push(single.text()); //Push value into country list
});
```

Comment: everytime it will push `ua`

Comment: @Durga I just noticed that too, fixed.

Comment: Why down voting? Please provide a reason so I can improve myself.

Answer (score 0):

I always wonder why it is so important, to mix a code with jquery just for a sake of using jquery.

It could be as simple as that (get nodes and map it to flat array with one simple check):

```
var nodesArray = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("#some_select option")).map(function(v){return (v.innerText == 'United States of America') ? 'United States' : v.innerText});
console.log(nodesArray.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

$(this).text() == "United States"; is the line with issue.

"==" is the comparison expression and not the assignment expression.

to assign value to this just use $(this).text("any text you want")